# React how to fetch data from multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

From Starships I get only array of URLs I would like to fetch these URL addresses and get name of each starship. I tried to do it through map array but I probably don´t know to write it. Do you have any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        movies:[],
        starships:[],
    } 
  }

  //we fetch all data and store it to movies
  async componentDidMount() {
    return await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/films/")
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => 
      this.setState({
        movies: data.results
      })   
    )      
  }
  

  render(){
    console.log(this.state.movies);
    return (
      <div className="App">
            <h1>Movies</h1>
            <div className="moviesList">
               {this.state.movies.map((movie, index) => {
              return  <p key={index} >{movie.title}</p> 
               })}
            </div>
            <div className="starshipsList">
               {this.state.movies.map((starship, index) => {
               return  <p key={index} >{starship.starships}</p>
               })}
            </div>

       
      </div>
  );
}

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the API doesn't provide another endpoint for starships as what are you trying to do isn't a best approach in my opinion.
But if it doesn't and you still need starship list, something like this could work:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  // get movies
  const moviesResult = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/films/");
  const movies = await moviesResult.json();
  // get array of all urls
  const starshipsUrls = movies.results.reduce((acc, movie) => {
    return acc.concat(movie.starships);
  },[]);
  // map over the urls and use promise.all to fetch
  const starshipsResult = await Promise.all(starshipsUrls.map(url=> fetch(url)));
  const starships = starshipsResult.json();

  this.setState({
    movies,
    starships
  });     
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunatelly it showing me this error:                                  Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): starshipsResult.json is not a function